# Javascript formData to array

Tags: javascript, forms, form-data

How do I "convert" formData to an array?

This works well for me but it does not seems to work well in all browsers:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/entries

Is there a way to do the same thing with support for older browsers?

```
var form_data = new FormData(this);
var form_array = [];

for(var pair of formData.entries()) {
   form_array[pair[0]] = pair[1];
}
```

### Update

I tried this without luck:

```
var entries = form_data.entries();

for (var i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
    console.log(entries[i]);
}
console.log(entries);
```

It gave

```
Iterator {}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On **modern browsers** you can use [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) to get a list of key/value pairs, or [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) to transform the `FormData` into a standard object.

```js
const formData = new FormData();

formData.append("question", "Life, Universe, Everything")
formData.append("answer", 42);
formData.append("isItTrue", false);

// An array of [key, value] pairs.
const pairs = Array.from(formData);

// An object with { key: values }.
const obj = Object.fromEntries(formData);

console.log(pairs);
console.log(obj);
```

From MDN:

> The **`Array.from()`** method creates a new, shallow-copied `Array` instance from an array-like or iterable object.

> The **`Object.fromEntries()`** static method transforms a list of key-value pairs into an object.

However for **legacy browser** (without polyfills) you must unpack the iterator manually:

```js
var formData = new FormData(document.forms[0])
var formArray = [];

formData.forEach(function(value) {
  formArray.push(value);
});

console.log(formArray);
```

```html
<form>
  <input name="foo" value="5">
  <input name="bar" value="42">
</form>
```

If you want to save the name-value pairs you should iterate over the form instead:

```js
var form = document.forms[0];
var formArray = [];

for (var i = 0; i < form.length; i += 1) {
  formArray.push({ name: form[i].name, value: form[i].value });
}

console.log(formArray);
```

```html
<form>
  <input name="foo" value="5">
  <input name="bar" value="42">
</form>
```

Comment: For me, Array.from, given the 'elements' collection of a form, resulted in an array of form elements, not an array of pairs {name,value}. Given a form control that has name A and value 3, I would like to find {A:3...} or [[A,3]...].

Comment: @DavidSpector That happens if you iterate over the `<Form>` elements as opposed to the `FormData`. This question is asking for the `FormData`. See your answer for the former. I’ll update the answer to give answer for key value pairs (which is done using `FormData.entries()`)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a [look at this w3shcools example](http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_form_elements)

```
var x = document.getElementById("frm1");
var text = "";
var i;
for (i = 0; i < x.length ;i++) {
    text += x.elements[i].value + "<br>";
}
```

Comment: I updated my question. I tried your solution but could not make it work.

Answer (score 0):

may be

```js
var form_data = new FormData(this);
var array_data = [...form_data]; // ya this works
```

Comment: While correct, the question specifically asks for support for older browser. This answer is really just rewording the question since `[...form_data]` is another way of writing the `for ... of` loop in the question.

Answer (score 0):

This code generates an object listing the names and values of all the fields in an example form:

```
var form=document.getElementById(formID);
var pairs={};
for (var i=0; i<form.length ;i++)
    pairs[form[i].name]=form[i].value;
j=JSON.stringify(pairs,null,3);
alert(j);
```